# How to add to a list you're returning?

Tags: scala

Sorry if this is a stupid question as I am a total beginner. I have a function `factors` which looks like this:

```
def factors (n:Int):List[Int] = {
  var xs = List[Int]()
  for(i <- 2 to (n-1)) {
    if(n%i==0) {xs :+ i}
  }
  return xs
}
```

However if I do `println(factors(10))` I always get `List()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RobertHarvey From the link you sent, `+=` is applied to `ListBuffer`, not `List`. I tried that and I got an error `value += is not a member of List[Int]`.

Comment: Suggest using `-Xlint`: "local var xs in method factors is never updated"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:+` operation returns a new List, you never assign it to xs.

```
def factors (n:Int):List[Int] = {
  var xs = List[Int]()
  for (i <- 2 to (n - 1)) {
    if(n%i==0) {xs = xs :+ i}
  }
  return xs
}
```

But, you really shouldn't be using `var`. We don't like them very much in Scala.
Also don't don't don't use return in Scala. It is a much more loaded keyword than you might think. Read about it [here](http://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html)

Here is a better way of doing this.

```
def factors (n:Int): List[Int] =
  for {
    i <- (2 to (n - 1)).toList
    if (n % i) == 0
  } yield i

factors(10)
```

You don't need `.toList` either but didn't want to mess with your return types. You are welcome to adjust

Working link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/haGESfhKRxqDdDIpaHXfpw

Comment: Or `Iterator.range(start = 2, end = n).filter(i => (n % i) == 0).toList`

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this problem as a filtering operation. You start with all the possible factors and you keep the ones where the remainder when dividing the input by that number is 0. The operation that does this in Scala is `filter`, which keeps values where a particular test is true and removes the others:

```
def factors(n: Int): List[Int] =
  (2 until n).filter(n % _ == 0).toList
```

To keep the code short I have also used the short form of a function where `_` stands for the argument to the function, so `n % _` means `n` divided by the current number that is being tested.